# Make two text views in relative layout occupy 50% of height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom list view with the following item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/text1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end_point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/start_point"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/text1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows mostly like I want except that `start_point` and `end_point` are not equal in height. I have tried many things but ended either in syntax error or in broken layout. Is there any working solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It shows mostly like I want except that start_point and end_point are
>   not equal in height. I have tried many things but ended either in
>   syntax error or in broken layout. Is there any working solution to
>   achieve that?

Insert an extra view in the layout before the two `TextViews` like this which will act as an anchor for giving equal amount of space for the `TextViews`:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    // the icon and the first TextView here

    <View android:id="@+id/anchor" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    // the two TextView below it
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/start_point" android:layout_above="@id/anchor" // the rest of the attributes />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/end_point" android:layout_below="@id/anchor" // the rest of the attributes />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. One comment: `layout_centerVertical` instead of `centerVertical`.